# Angular4 : Slider change should trigger separate functions for separate range values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular, typescript

I am using a slider in Angular 4. Below is my code in HTML:

```
  <div oninput="range1value.value = range1.valueAsNumber" id="range">
                    Actual/Optimised
                    <input name="range1" type="range" step="1" min="1" max="3" value="1" (onRangeChanged)="onRangeChange"> Adjusted
                    </div>
```

I want the slider to trigger a function Max() when it is on the maximum range and I want it to trigger separate function Min() when it is on the minimum range.
Please help.

Regards

Neha

Comment: You don't need to make two functions because you can handle this inside the function by checking the value of the input.

Comment: @SurjeetBhadauriya I am new to angular. How can i achieve it?

Comment: I have added the answer. Please go through with that.

Comment: @SurjeetBhadauriya Fantastic.Thank you.

Comment: Pleasure @Neha. Please mark it right.

Comment: @SurjeetBhadauriya Done :)

Comment: Thanks, Neha! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this thing by making a function in the component.

**Component**

*In the below function, you can do whatever you want.*

```
  onChangeRange(rangeValue: any){
    console.log(rangeValue);
    if(rangeValue == 1){
       //do something
     }else if(rangeValue == 3){
       //do something else
     }else{
       //do something else
     }
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<input name="range1" type="range" step="1" min="1" max="3" [(ngModel)]="rangeValue" (change)="onChangeRange(rangeValue)"> Adjusted
```

**Explanation**

**rangeValue**: this contains the value of the range.

**onChangeRange**: this is a function which will call when you change the range.